# nonlinear second order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

can someone give me a hint on how to solve this second order nonlinear ODE. $d^2u/dt^2 = 2u^3$ I know i can let $v=u'$ but i'm unsure if this is the correct method to use?

thanks

Comment: Hint :Let $p= \frac{du}{dt}$ then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} =\frac{du}{dt} \frac{d}{du} \left( \frac{du}{dt} \right) = p \frac{dp}{du}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: so $p =u^2 +c$?

Comment: the solution containes the Jacobi-function

Comment: $p^2=u^4+C$. & DrSG says it will require Elliptic functions.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @DonaldSplutterwit, let $x = u'$, then, 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
u'' =u'\frac{d}{du} \left( u' \right) = x \frac{dx}{du} =2u^3
\end{eqnarray*}
Then integrate this expression:
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\int xdx = 2\int u^3du
\end{eqnarray*}
To give 
$$
u' = \pm \sqrt{u^4 + C}
$$
Which can be integrated in time to give:
$$
t = \int \frac{du }{\pm \sqrt{u^4 + C}}
$$
The integral to solve is tricky and must be reduced to another form (provided $C\neq 0$), we first need to figure out the limits, then let $u = 1/y$. From here substitute $y = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

multipliying both sides by $$\frac{du}{dt}$$ we get
$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\cdot \frac{du}{dt}=2\frac{du}{dt}u^3$$
then integrating both sides with respect to $t$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)^2=C_1+\frac{u(t)^2}{2}$$
then we get
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{2C_1+u(t)^4}$$
and now
$$\int \frac{\frac{du}{dt}dt}{\sqrt{2C_1+u(t)^4}}=\pm1dt$$
and now good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The equation given is
$$\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}=2u^3$$
where $t$ is the independent variable and $u$ is the dependent variable.

**REDUCTION OF ORDER**

- When independent variable is absent, set $p=u'\implies u''=p\dfrac{dp}{du}$
- When independent variable is present, set $p=u'\implies u''=p'$

For our equation, it is missing the independent variable $t$, so we set $p=u'\implies u''=p\dfrac{dp}{du}$

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dt^2}&=2u^3\\p\dfrac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm du}&=2u^3\\\int p\,\mathrm dp&=\int2u^3\,\mathrm du\\\dfrac12p^2&=\dfrac12u^4+C_1\\p^2&=u^4+C_2\\\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}&=\pm\sqrt{u^4+C_2}\\\int\pm\sqrt{u^4+C_2}\mathrm \,du&=\int \mathrm dt\\t&=\int\pm\sqrt{u^4+C_2}\,\mathrm du\end{align}\tag*{}$$

From here, the problem becomes a bit difficult to solve, I'll keep it up to this for now